# Web scrape with rvest from a table that is not defined

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to get a table from this 
website :
http://www.oddsportal.com/american-football/usa/nfl-2012-2013/results/

I actually want to get the table in the middle of the page.

I tried different ways but in vain.

```
library("rvest")
library(dplyr)

url1 <- "http://www.oddsportal.com/american-football/usa/nfl-2012-2013/results/"
table <- url1 %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="tournamentTable"]') %>% 
  html_table(fill = T)
```

This does not work because i believe that the table is not defined as table.

I also tried to grab the rows separately  by using:

```
 df <- mps1 %>% 
     html_nodes(css = "tr.odd.deactivate,tr.center.nob-border")
```

but it obtains nothing.

Any idea how can I do it?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on previous questions by people trying to scrape from this site, this table is probably dynamically generated.  As far as I know, the only way to deal with pages like this is to use `RSelenium` - which basically automates a browser.

After a lot of trial and error, the following code seems to work (using Chrome on Windows 10)...

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url <- "http://www.oddsportal.com/american-football/usa/nfl-2012-2013/results/"
rD <- rsDriver(port=4444L,browser="chrome")
remDr <- rD$client

remDr$navigate(url)

page <- remDr$getPageSource()
remDr$close() #you can leave open if you are doing several of these: close at the end

table <- page[[1]] %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//table[@id="tournamentTable"]') %>% #specify table as there is a div with same id
  html_table(fill = T)

table <- table[[1]]

head(table)

  American Football» USA»NFL 2012/2013   American Football» USA»NFL 2012/2013   American Football» USA»NFL 2012/2013 American Football» USA»NFL 2012/2013 American Football» USA»NFL 2012/2013 American Football» USA»NFL 2012/2013
1              03 Feb 2013 - Play Offs                03 Feb 2013 - Play Offs                03 Feb 2013 - Play Offs              03 Feb 2013 - Play Offs                                 1.00                                 2.00
2                                                                                                                                                                                           NA                                   NA
3                                23:30 San Francisco 49ers - Baltimore Ravens San Francisco 49ers - Baltimore Ravens                                31:34                                 1.49                                 2.71
4              28 Jan 2013 - All Stars                28 Jan 2013 - All Stars                28 Jan 2013 - All Stars              28 Jan 2013 - All Stars                                 1.00                                 2.00
5                                                                                                                                                                                           NA                                   NA
6                                00:00                              NFC - AFC                              NFC - AFC                                62:35                                 2.03                                 1.83
  American Football» USA»NFL 2012/2013
1                                  B's
2                                     
3                                    9
4                                  B's
5                                     
6                                    9
```

The odds are coming out as decimal numbers, unfortunately, but hopefully you can work with that.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought that RSelenium is used to navigate in the page. (click buttons, etc)